# Changed my laptops name and now windows 10 won't let me log in

Tags: windows-10

My situation...

I have a 5 year old Win10 laptop with 2 login accounts both with administrator rights

Main account used - C#######@outlook.com.
Secondary used - is local account

When the laptop was first setup, the main account was setup with a finger print login option only - no password was ever set up for this. However my mobile cell phone was also used at that time when the outlook account was setup.

Yesterday I changed the name of the laptop to make it something more appropriate. This was done through the "settings" option within Win10. My Laptop was online at the time.

After doing this, I restarted my laptop for the changes to take effect. When the login screen appeared, repeated attempts to log in with the finger print scanner failed. I restarted the laptop several times, all with the same outcome.

Given I had no other login option setup, I clicked on "forgot password" and proceeded to change it. I received a text confirmation to my mobile cell phone used originally in setting up the outlook account, allowing me to change the password.

From that point, I have not been able to log in with the new password. I restarted the laptop several times, all with the same outcome. Each time I enter the new password I receive the message "Your device is offline. Please sign in with the last password used on this device". I am actually online and connected via wifi. I also tried this with a physical LAN connection with the same outcome.

I can however log in as normal using the other local account.

This is my main work laptop and I need to recover this login. Can anyone suggest anything or point me in the right direction??

Many thanks in advance

Comment: C#######@outlook.com. is a Microsoft Account.  Go to Microsoft Account Login and add a password to the account.

Comment: "This is my main work laptop, and I need to recover this log in." - If it's owned by a company, have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance?

Comment: @john, I have already done that with no success

Comment: @Ramhound. I am the IT administrator/owner/cleaner/tea person/goffer, etc. I think you get the picture

Comment: Take ownership of the profile to recover your documents and make a new Account.